# formatting datetime to varchar with padded zeros

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, formatting

I have the following field called "MaterialPrice". It is a data type of -

```
DECIMAL (18,2)
```

So a sample values is "10.88"

What I need to change it to is something like below -

```
0000000000000**1088**0
```

So the field length is 18, where the last character (to the left is always 0) and the characters in front of the original value are padded with zeros also.

Another example would be

```
501.02
```

would be

```
000000000000**50102**0
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure I understand the logic, 1 zero in the right of the number and padding until 18 chars to the left?

Comment: What about 1.00 or 0.00?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly the requirement, you could as the below:

```
DECLARE @val DECIMAL(18, 2) = 501.02
SELECT REPLICATE(0, 18 - LEN(@val)) + '**' + REPLACE(CAST(@val AS VARCHAR(50)), '.', '') + '**0'
```

Result:  `000000000000**50102**0`

Answer (score 0):

I would:

1. Multiply by 100,
2. cast to string,
3. Measure length,
4. Concatenate: (17-length) "0"s, "**", the string number and "**0